# Using malloc() and other functions in C using Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

This is the first time I've used Eclipse for writing C code, so the answer might be very simple. I'm also figuring that Eclipse is already setup to compile, build, and link appropriately. This is being ran on a Windows 7 64-bit machine.

In my C code, it seems that anytime I use the `malloc()` or even `printf()` function it puts the red squiggly line below it. Just the function is underlined, not the casting or even the parameters.

Here is what the line of code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int* list; //This is a global variable

int main(){

    //...inside a function
    list = (int*) malloc( sizeof(int) ); // Out of this line, only the word "malloc" is underlined in red.
    printf(""); //printf also gives me an error

    return 0;
}
```

When I hover my mouse over the error, it says the following:

> Function 'malloc' could not be resolved.

Am I even using `malloc()` right?

Comment: Are you remembering to `#include <stdlib.h>`?

Comment: If you're writing C (not C++), you're not doing this right - [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: what error do you get? If it is underlined with red it should be an error there.

Comment: @GrahamBorland yes, `#include <stdlib.h>` is included. Made sure of that.

Comment: Does it still compile, regardless of the hover message?

Comment: @teppic Nope. Doesn't compile.

Comment: I thought it was `malloc.h` that you needed to include...

Comment: What's the error message in the console window when you try to compile?

Comment: Is this an Android project? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686931/eclipse-cdt-fails-to-find-stl-symbols-in-ndk-project

Comment: I deleted my answer because it was just worth a comment, but I don't know, I've always been told not to cast my `malloc`'s results : `int* list; list = malloc(sizeof(int));`

Comment: I'm going to guess that it's because `stdlib.h` isn't installed (e.g. on Linux the development headers aren't properly installed). That'd be clear from the compiler error though. If not though, what's the platform? Which compiler?

Comment: @teppic How do I install the compiler onto Eclipse?

Comment: @teppic Or install any of the `*.h`s like `stdlib.h`

Comment: @RobAveryIV: you need to supply more info. Are you using Windows, OS X or Linux? And if Linux, which distribution?

Comment: @teppic On a Windows 7 64-bit machine. I added it to my answer.

Comment: Is this snippet *inside the body of a function?*. Function calls (and other code) are not allowed in global scope.

Comment: @wildplasser the pointer is a global variable, but the malloc function isn't. The malloc function is inside a function.

Comment: @RobAveryIV: Can you compile any standard library functions (e.g. `printf`) or is it just `malloc` that gives a problem? When you compile the project the console window at the bottom will show the output from the compilation, and the compiler error -- that's needed.

Comment: Why don't you show the real code, instead of forcing us to ask obvious questions, or guess the missing parts ?

Comment: the code compiles without the malloc? Eclipse find stdlib.h?

Comment: Well, obviously Eclipse (just like the compiler) must have a means to enable it to locate the directories with the header files. Could be an environment variable, configuration setting, or a config file.

Comment: Your call is legal. As a matter of style, it would be better written as `list = malloc(sizeof *list);`, but that doesn't explain the complaint you're getting. But regardless of the red squiggly line, does your code compile and run? (`<stdlib.h>` is a C standard header; if Eclipse can't find it, it's badly misconfigured.)

Comment: @Bingo: No, there is no standard `malloc.h` header. The ISO C standard says that `malloc` is declared in `<stdlib.h>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't provided enough information. You need to provide a complete program including `malloc`, however small, that doesn't compile. You also need to give the compiler error you get, and whether the problem is just with `malloc` or all standard library functions.

At a guess, your compiler software isn't installed correctly and it can't find `stdlib.h`.

As you've now added that no standard library functions work, there's definitely a problem with your compiler set up (this is nothing to do with `malloc`).

Comment: I think your right. How can I do that, or can you point me in a good direction?

Comment: @RobAveryIV Check your compiler's fully installed. You haven't said which it is - gcc? A plugin for Visual Studio? If the question is more 'how do I install eclipse on Windows for C/C++', it's a bit too broad for this question.

Answer (score 1):

According to the clang and the cc compilers, your code is ok and it compiles in Eclipse Juno:

```
Building target: code
Invoking: GCC C Linker
gcc  -o "code"  ./code.o   
Finished building target: code
```

I think you can look at this question

["Unresolved inclusion" error with Eclipse CDT for C standard library headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337757/unresolved-inclusion-stdio-h)

if you want a complete solution.